# Simple question on how to format a number

Tags: php, number-formatting

my question is the following and I guess is really simple.
I have a number echoed with PHP. For example 37452.
I would like to have a dot and be displayed like 37.452

My var is `$numposts`

How is this possible ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you wanting to put a dot before the last 3 numbers, then?  Like comma notation for large numbers (1,250,200)?  Or is the position arbitrary?

Comment: Well I guess any of these solutions would be great. Whatever is easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php). The signature is:

```
string number_format ( 
    float $number , int $decimals = 0 , 
    string $dec_point = '.' , string $thousands_sep = ',' 
)
```

Example:

```
<?php

echo number_format(37452) . "\n";
// 37,452

echo number_format(37452, 0, ',', '.') . "\n";
// 37.452

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use number_format with custom decimal and thousands characters.

```
number_format(37452, 0, ',', '.');
```

Answer (score 0):

As The MYYN correctly mentions, you should check out the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

In your example, you could use it as such:

```
echo number_format($numposts, 3, ',', '.');
```